I'm trying to start a celery worker (connecting to RabbitMQ). It is failing
celery -A shop worker -l info
[2024-08-17 13:31:27,736: WARNING/MainProcess] No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'localhost'
 
 -------------- celery@famous-koala v5.4.0 (opalescent)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-116-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2024-08-17 13:31:27
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         shop:0x7f352527c070
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery

I'm running this on a remote VM, so I would like to specify both the IP and username/password. I cannot find information on how to do that.
I tried the docs: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker
I could not figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

try this :
celery -A shop worker -l info --hostname amqp://user:password@localhost:5672/myvhost

